# Unable to change HTML element <h1> to a <form> as a function response to HTTPS request using node.js (Express)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

If I try to change "

## Hello World

" to
"label>Your Name
it fails to render. what a i doing wrong? See code below...

---

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/currenttime", function (request, response) {
  response.send("<h1>" + new Date().toDateString() + "</h1>");
}); // localhost:3000/currenttime

app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  response.send("<form><label>Your Name</label><input type='text'></form>");
}); //localhost:3000/

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add closing tag for your input element.

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/currenttime", function (request, response) {
  response.send("<h1>" + new Date().toDateString() + "</h1>");
}); // localhost:3000/currenttime

app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  response.send("<form><label>Your Name</label><input type='text' / ></form>");
}); //localhost:3000/

app.listen(3000);
```